# IDE: C++ syntax errors on std::tr1

Tags: c++, netbeans, syntax

Say I have something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tr1/functional>

void bar(int value) {
   // do something with value
}

void foo() {
   // v is a std::vector<int>
   std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(),
       std::tr1::bind(&bar, std::tr1::placeholders::_1)); // netbeans marks bind and placeholders
}
```

NetBeans marks bind/placeholders as "Unable to resolve identifier ...".
And it doesn't autocomplete too...

Strange fact is, it has no problema autocompleting `#include <tr1/functional>` which seems to indicate
thate the CodeAssistant paths are configured correctly. It doesn't marks the **_1**
in `std::tr1::placeholders::_1` as "unable to resolve...", too.

Code compiles fine, though.

Any hints on what to configure/look for? It's very annoying seeing lots of "error" markings on perfectly fine code.

Comment: ops... you're right... edited

Comment: I use NetBeans extensively for c++ development and have accepted the fact that it can't parse some of TR1 and Boost correctly.  I haven't been able to find anything to fix this, so I'm excited to see if someone has a solution.  @Mr Shunz: Out of curiosity, are the symbols it cannot resolve consistent from each restart of NetBeans?

Comment: @JaredC Yes, they're always the same symbols. But sometimes it cannot parse successfully some standard STL ::iterator typedefs, too. But it gets them right after a forced reparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm prone to think that Netbeans' parser isn't able to correctly parse some stuff in `std::tr1`.

`std::tr1` is not part of C++03, but will most likely be part of C++0x; for this reason many STL implementation use other C++0x features to implement it, for example the `std::tr1::bind` supplied by GCC 4.5.2 is implemented as a variadic template function.

If Netbeans' parser doesn't support variadic templates yet, it will fail parsing it, and the result is what you got.

I've got similar problems with QtCreator (which [doesn't even support namespace aliases](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTCREATORBUG-166)).

If this is the case you only have to wait for an update. You could submit a bug report, if it hasn't already been submitted.

Comment: i think you're right, i'm waiting the 7.0 version for proper PHP 5.3 and HTML5 support, too ;) Even if this page: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB70#C.2FC.2B.2B_Support seems to indicate that C++ enhancements are just to auto convert "." to "->" for pointer objects.